# SwiftUI - Snapshot a variable as a value instead of a pointer so it is not updated during DragGesture .onchanged lifecycle

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to move a CGPoint (greenPoint) by moving another one (bluePoint). The distance and angle must remained the same. In order to capture that, I store the x delta as adjacent and y delta as opposite. My issue is that when I move the blue point, the adjacent and opposite values get updated and therefore the greenPoint stays in the same place.
I was thinking I could maybe take a snapshot of the values before the .onChanged, but can’t work out how? Code is below.

```
Circle()
                .strokeBorder(.white, lineWidth: 2)
                .background(Circle().fill(.blue))
                .frame(width:10, height:10)
                .position(bluePoint)
                .gesture(DragGesture()
                            .onChanged{state in 
                    greenPoint = CGPoint(x: bluePoint.x+adjacent, y: bluePoint.y+opposite)
                    bluePoint = state.location
                })
```

Note: I need to keep adjacent and opposite as variables rather than static values, because in another part of the code moving the greenPoint is permitted while the bluePoint stays still.

Thanks!

Comment: Update: I tried the following code, but it started to exponentially scale: greenPoint.y = greenPoint.y + state.translation.height 
                    greenPoint.x = greenPoint.x + state.translation.width

Comment: When doing this kind of math, you must check that you reset the translation between 2 updates : the value you get is the translation since the beginning and not since the last update. 2 ways : memorise green point position before first move or reset translation when it has been used.

Comment: Thanks Pitt Xav. That helped my understand to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestions. Got it to work with the following:

```
        let adj = baseCoords.adjacent
        let op = baseCoords.opposite
…

Circle()
                .strokeBorder(.white, lineWidth:2)
                .background(Circle().fill(.blue))
                .frame(width:12, height:12)
                .position(bluePoint)
                .gesture(DragGesture()
                            .onChanged{state in 
                    bluePoint = state.location
                    greenPoint.x = bluePoint.x + adj
                    greenPoint.y = bluePoint.y + op
                }
                )
```

By copying into 2 new variables, the adj and op values do not update during the .onChanged.